# How to access postgres-docker container other docker container without ip address

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

How to access postgres-docker container other docker container without ip address?
I want to store data in postgres by using myweb. in jar given host like localhost:5432/db..

Here my compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
   myweb:
    build: ./myweb
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9090:9090"
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
    depends_on:
      - "postgresdb"

   postgresdb:
    build: ./mydb
    image: ppk:postgres9.5
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
     - back-tier

volumes:
   dbdata: {}

networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:
```

Comment: I tried -link  option , able to get only ENV values , not  accessing postgres .

Comment: Have you tried adding `network_mode: host` to your docker compose service? In this way, containers can share local ethernet iface.

Comment: Yes , i tried with network_mode: host , it also not working ...

Comment: my app docker not recognise postgres containter, any other solution..?

Comment: Have you added network_mode: host to both services or just one?

Comment: What do you mean by _my app docker not recognise postgres containter_ ? From where do you know that?

Comment: I added both container as  host networks...
and myapp docker means java application runing with port 8080  , other postgres docker container .i want to communicate myapp container to postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `localhost:5432/db..` use `postgresdb:5432/db..` connection string.

By default the container has the same hostname as the service name.

---

Here is my minimal working example, which is connecting a java client (boxfuse/flyway) with postgres server. The most important part is the **heath check**, which is delaying the start of the `myweb` container to the time when postgres is ready to accept connections.

Note that **this can be directly executed** by `docker-compose up`, it dosen't have any other dependencies. Both the images are from docker hub.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
   myweb:
    image: boxfuse/flyway
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb/postgres -user=postgres -password=123 info
    depends_on:
      postgresdb:
        condition: service_healthy

   postgresdb:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready -q -U postgres"
```

Comment: I tried postgresdb:5432/db.. it also not working, my app container not recognise postgres container.

Comment: @phanip What is the output of `docker exec app ping postgresdb` ? Did you try restarting the whole docker daemon?

Comment: Its pinging with each other , postgredb not accessing in app docker ,even i enabled localhost=* and ,0.0.0.0 md5 respective files

Comment: @phanip **When ping is ok then there is no problem with docker setup.** Your problem seems to be in the config of your database. The docker network is ok...

Comment: @phanip I added a minimal working example to my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried with working example i got error like ...
ERROR: for myweb  Cannot start service myweb: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb/postgres\": stat -url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb/postgres: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: @phanip I think you made some changes in the docker compose file, did you? You have to post the whole compose file, which is causing the problem. I thing you have to change the `command` setting according to your needs and conditions. My `command` is only usable with the boxfuse/flyway image.

Comment: yes i changed according to my requirement,  i ran java app which using postgres  as db , when i ran my app data will store on postgres container , my app and postgres are diffrent containers.

Answer (score 0):

That is the `Docker Networking` problem. The solution is to use `postgresdb:5432/db` in place of `localhost:5432/db` because the two service is in the same network named back-tier and docker deamon will use name service like a DNS name to make communication between the two container. I think that my solution will help you so.